# No DLLs are installed with OpenCV Prebuilt binaries

Tags: windows, opencv, dll, directory, installation

I used the Windows OpenCV installer to install the latest version, and I cannot find any dlls installed after the installer extracts the files out to my directory. I read that all the major dlls', including the core libraries and calibration libraries are included in $OPENCV_DIR/build/x64/bin , but this directory only has a few files, and none of the ones mentioned in the tutorial.

Here is my file directory:

[image: image description]

As shown there, there are no dll's located in this directory. I have also looked at the corresponding vc11 and x86 directories, and they have the same set of files. I am sure I am not doing anything wrong, but I don't see where the dlls' are installed. Library files located in the staticlib folder, but those are not what I need. Am I missing a step when installing Opencv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV `world` is a module that combines all other modules. From [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3614/what-is-opencv_world-package-in-opencv-243-rc/):

> The new super-module modestly called opencv_world has been introduced. It combines all the other modules selected by user and thus it's much more convenient for redistribution, comparing to ~20 shared libraries libopencv_core, libopencv_imgproc etc. The module takes ~10-15Mb and it is linked from the same object files (their union) as the other modules, so the overall OpenCV compile time increased by just a few seconds.

Just link to `opencv_world300(d).lib` found in `lib` folder, and copy  `opencv_world300(d).dll` near the `.exe`, or add `bin` folder to `PATH`, and you're done.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. The tutorials are really out of date and should be up to date.